# After submit redirect to another page not with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have couple of identical HTML pages which take user input and with PHP I save the input on text files. As it's always the same I would like to apply the same PHP on every html page. So my question is if there is a way to redirect to the next html page but not through PHP, so that the PHP can be reusable for all the pages?

Because if I add `onclick="window.location.href='/main2.html'` then the PHP is not fired up or if I change action="main2.html" then again the PHP is not included. Or if I add `header("Location: main2.html");` then it cannot really be applied to all the html pages, as it goes main.html -> main2.html -> main3.html etc.

HTML 1:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
        <input type="text" name="address" required>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="intro">
</form>
```

HTML 2:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
        <input type="text" name="address" required>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("text.txt", "a+");

    $address = $_POST['address'].";";
    fwrite($myfile, $address);

    //header("Location: main2.html");
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if all the forms are the same, then create a function, pass it to a .php file then return a success/error, in the success callback of the ajax function, use `window.location.href = 'desired_location.html'`

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't want to use PHP, it can make this pretty simple for you. You can use the session variable in PHP to track the user, the entries he has made and even allow them to go back and forward.
You can read more on it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm).

You can redirect the user based on the session counter or the source from where the call is made and direct them accordingly to the next page. This makes your code scalable as well.

So you code will be something like this:

```
   session_start();

   if( isset( $_SESSION['counter'] ) ) {
      $_SESSION['counter'] += 1;
   }else {
      $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
   }

   $newURL = "HTMLPage".$_SESSION['counter']."html";
   header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

The above code will redirect the user to the next page. PS: You will have to handle the case for your last html page.